# Replaced transmission now car wont start

Tags: diagnostics

Had my transmission replaced drove car for three days now it won't start. Lights and radio work. No crank no start. Replaced battery, starter, and starter relay.

PLEASE HELP HAVEN'T HAD MY CAR A YEAR BEEN CARLESS SINCE CHRISTMAS

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like a wiring issue or the ignition switch. Do the lights dim at all if you try to start it with the lights on? No clicking or anything as you turn the key? What is the year/make/model/engine of the car?

Comment: sounds like a bad connection or the neutral safety switch....hold it up in park tight with hand pressure and try to start it..if that dos not work try putting it in neutral  and starting it..if still not working properly then have the  wires to the starter ,the ground wires and the neutral safety switch checked unless you can do...if you need any help in that area text me or post here and ill try to explain in detail